# block elements - how to point event to text only

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to show the `title` (attr) 
only when the text is hovered.

The problem is that here we are talking about hovering `block` elements like `p` and `h1`.

So my question is: how to make title attribute appear (or any other event) only when the text is targeted (not all the width of the element)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/J6bUw/)

With jQuery so far I have:

### [THIS demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/7eQ7Z/)

```
$('h1, p').each(function(){

    $(this).wrapInner('<span></span>');
    var spann = $(this).children('span');
    var span = spann.width();
    $(this).children('span').contents().unwrap();

     $(this).css({
         width: span+'px',
     });

    if ( $(this).css('text-align') == 'center' ){   
        $(this).css({
            marginLeft:'auto',
            marginRight:'auto'
        });
    }

});
```

I actually add the `span` but temporally, just to make the position calculations.

But now the backgrounds are missing.... argh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dirty trick is inserting a `span` inside the elements. This isn't visible (it's inline), but has a width so that it just fits the text only.

This is an example for the `p`:

```
<p>
    <span title="I am a paragraph">Paragraph</span>
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J6bUw/1/

Comment: Thanks pimvdb for your prompt reply. As my Q includes jquery (I can't touch the html) so far I have: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/7eQ7Z/ But as you can see ... it's not exactly the same result...

Comment: Setting permanently span into h1 ... (this jQuery will be part of a plugin) A possible problem could result if someone have already set the `span` style in their .css, right?

Comment: @roXon: I'm not sure how to wrap dynamically generated elements. You're correct about the `span`, not sure how you can disable current `span` styles either.

Comment: I told wrong, [title] works with dynamically generated elements, I just encountered some issues in IE combined with hover, mouseleave, mouseout.

Comment: @roXon: That idea is not too bad actually! But in case they use `<font>`, you're in bad luck. You can also use your own invented element if you don't care about validity: http://jsfiddle.net/J6bUw/4/.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to show the `title` (attr) only when the text is hovered.

You can't.

> So my question is: how to make title attribute appear (or any other event) only when the text is targeted (not all the width of the element)

Wrap the text in an `inline` element, such as a `<span>`, and move the `title` to the `span`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/vmuQr/

---

To do the transformation with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/WyKgV/

Comment: Thanks Matt for your prompt reply. As my Q includes jquery (I can't touch the html) so far I have: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/7eQ7Z/ But as you can see ... it's not exactly the same result...

Comment: as this will be part of a plugin, I think that another problem would be if someone have already set a style css for `span` elements. Right? http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/WyKgV/2/

Comment: In my demo#2 I do set the span, but I remove it afterwards 'on the fly' after calculating text stuff... :|